# <tr> element remove() not working in second remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I Have code like below :

```
<tbody>
<tr name="a02323232">
<tr name="j03543434">
</tbody>
```

first i want to remove  element with :

```
$("tr[name='a02323232']").hide("slow");
```

second then i want to remove

```
$("tr[name='j03543434']").hide("slow");
```

in first try , its successfull to remove but in the second try its not working , then i trace that the mistake is the jquery still do remove() like the first try . so only just element in the first try is removed .
Maybe i wrong ? please help me .

Answer (score 2):

If you use legal HTML, it seems to work for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/V8LCK/.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr name="a02323232"><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr name="j03543434"><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if i just call with general jquery button click function its work for me too , but i call remove() or hide() in callback function from jquery ui.dialog . it is like jquery still keep browser chance .

Comment: I don't think we can help you (other than wild guesses) if you don't share with us more about the situation you have the problem in.  Can you make a reproducible case in a jsFiddle?